# Parsing FORMAT and sample value fields from VCF file

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, vcf-vcard, gatk

I am trying to load a vcf file (created using `GATK` using `data.table::fread`, and then parse the results of the `FORMAT` and `sample` fields, into different columns. The column names are given by the `FORMAT` field, with each element separated by a `:`. and the values for each of these columns is given by the `sample` field, with each corresponding value in the same order as the names in the `FORMAT` field, and equally separated by `:`. The issue I'm facing is that, for each VCF file, I have different values for the FORMAT field, at different rows.

For example, I extracted one row for each unique value found in the `FORMAT` field:

```r
structure(list(
  `#CHROM` = c("rs11218343_chr11_121564878_SORL1_C/T","rs16941239_chr16_86420604_FOXF1_A/T", 
               "rs7384878_chr7_100334426_SPDYE3_C/T", "rs3851179_chr11_86157598_EED_T/C", 
               "rs10868366_chr9_86085145_GOLM1_G/T", "rs11771145_chr7_143413669_EPHA1_A/G", 
               "rs6966331_chr7_37844191_EPDR1_T/C"),
  POS = c(722L, 1468L, 1367L, 1000L, 246L, 261L, 1384L), 
  ID = c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."), 
  REF = c("AGG", "G", "C", "T", "C", "T", "G"), 
  ALT = c(".", "*,GA", "T", "C", ".", "C", "."), 
  QUAL = c("29.91", ".", "40.64", "32690.06", ".", ".", "0.64"), 
  FILTER = c("LowQual", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "LowQual"),
  INFO = c("DP=5;MLEAC=.;MLEAF=.;MQ=26.79", ".",
           "AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=1.29;DP=20;ExcessHet=0.0000;FS=2.963;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=43.87;MQRankSum=-1.058e+00;QD=2.90;ReadPosRankSum=0.697;SOR=1.802",
           "AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=1097;ExcessHet=0.0000;FS=0.000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=60.00;QD=31.02;SOR=0.776",
           ".", ".", "BaseQRankSum=-9.670e-01;DP=3;ExcessHet=0.00;MLEAC=.;MLEAF=.;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;ReadPosRankSum=0.967"),
  FORMAT = c("GT", "GT:AD", "GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL:PS", "GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL", 
             "GT:AD:DP:RGQ", "GT:AD:PGT:PID:PS", "GT:DP:RGQ"), 
  F1601764_S460_L002 = c("0/0", "./.:0,0,0", "0|1:12,2:14:48:0|1:1344_G_A:48,0,498:1344",
                         "1/1:0,1054:1054:99:32704,3160,0", "0/0:0:0:0", ".|.:0,0:0|1:251_T_C:251",
                         "0/0:3:16")), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA, -7L))
#>                                 #CHROM  POS ID REF  ALT     QUAL  FILTER
#> 1 rs11218343_chr11_121564878_SORL1_C/T  722  . AGG    .    29.91 LowQual
#> 2  rs16941239_chr16_86420604_FOXF1_A/T 1468  .   G *,GA        .       .
#> 3  rs7384878_chr7_100334426_SPDYE3_C/T 1367  .   C    T    40.64       .
#> 4     rs3851179_chr11_86157598_EED_T/C 1000  .   T    C 32690.06       .
#> 5   rs10868366_chr9_86085145_GOLM1_G/T  246  .   C    .        .       .
#> 6  rs11771145_chr7_143413669_EPHA1_A/G  261  .   T    C        .       .
#> 7    rs6966331_chr7_37844191_EPDR1_T/C 1384  .   G    .     0.64 LowQual
#>                                                                                                                                                            INFO
#> 1                                                                                                                                 DP=5;MLEAC=.;MLEAF=.;MQ=26.79
#> 2                                                                                                                                                             .
#> 3 AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=1.29;DP=20;ExcessHet=0.0000;FS=2.963;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=43.87;MQRankSum=-1.058e+00;QD=2.90;ReadPosRankSum=0.697;SOR=1.802
#> 4                                                            AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=1097;ExcessHet=0.0000;FS=0.000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=60.00;QD=31.02;SOR=0.776
#> 5                                                                                                                                                             .
#> 6                                                                                                                                                             .
#> 7                                                      BaseQRankSum=-9.670e-01;DP=3;ExcessHet=0.00;MLEAC=.;MLEAF=.;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;ReadPosRankSum=0.967
#>                      FORMAT                        F1601764_S460_L002
#> 1                        GT                                       0/0
#> 2                     GT:AD                                 ./.:0,0,0
#> 3 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL:PS 0|1:12,2:14:48:0|1:1344_G_A:48,0,498:1344
#> 4            GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL           1/1:0,1054:1054:99:32704,3160,0
#> 5              GT:AD:DP:RGQ                                 0/0:0:0:0
#> 6          GT:AD:PGT:PID:PS                   .|.:0,0:0|1:251_T_C:251
#> 7                 GT:DP:RGQ                                  0/0:3:16
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

What I would like to do, is to find a way to go over every row and separate the values in `F1601764_S460_L002` to the corresponding columns given by the elements in the `FORMAT` field (separated by `:`).

I started by doing this with `data.table::fread` and `tidyr::separate_wider_delim`, thinking that all `FORMAT` field were: `GT:AD:DP:RGQ` or `GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL`. But this, obviously, yield problems.

I also tried the `vcfR` package, but I feel it's too slow for what I need to do.

What I would like to achieve, in the end, is using a `tdyr` approach to achieve something like this:

```r
structure(list(`#CHROM` = c("rs6966331_chr7_37844191_EPDR1_T/C", 
"rs7384878_chr7_100334426_SPDYE3_C/T", "rs11771145_chr7_143413669_EPHA1_A/G", 
"rs10868366_chr9_86085145_GOLM1_G/T", "rs3851179_chr11_86157598_EED_T/C", 
"rs11218343_chr11_121564878_SORL1_C/T", "rs16941239_chr16_86420604_FOXF1_A/T"
), POS = c(1384L, 1367L, 261L, 246L, 1000L, 722L, 1468L), AD = c(NA, 
"12,2", "0,0", "0", "0,1054", NA, "0,0,0"), DP = c(3L, 14L, NA, 
0L, 1054L, NA, NA), GQ = c(NA, 48L, NA, NA, 99L, NA, NA), GT = c("0/0", 
"0|1", NA, "0/0", "1/1", "0/0", NA), PGT = c(NA, "0|1", "0|1", 
NA, NA, NA, NA), PID = c(NA, "1344_G_A", "251_T_C", NA, NA, NA, 
NA), PL = c(NA, "48,0,498", NA, NA, "32704,3160,0", NA, NA), 
    PS = c(NA, 1344L, 251L, NA, NA, NA, NA), RGQ = c(16L, NA, 
    NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA), SB = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), GT_alleles = c("G/G", "C|T", ".", "C/C", 
    "C/C", "AGG/AGG", ".")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
#>                                 #CHROM  POS     AD   DP GQ   GT  PGT      PID
#> 1    rs6966331_chr7_37844191_EPDR1_T/C 1384   <NA>    3 NA  0/0 <NA>     <NA>
#> 2  rs7384878_chr7_100334426_SPDYE3_C/T 1367   12,2   14 48  0|1  0|1 1344_G_A
#> 3  rs11771145_chr7_143413669_EPHA1_A/G  261    0,0   NA NA <NA>  0|1  251_T_C
#> 4   rs10868366_chr9_86085145_GOLM1_G/T  246      0    0 NA  0/0 <NA>     <NA>
#> 5     rs3851179_chr11_86157598_EED_T/C 1000 0,1054 1054 99  1/1 <NA>     <NA>
#> 6 rs11218343_chr11_121564878_SORL1_C/T  722   <NA>   NA NA  0/0 <NA>     <NA>
#> 7  rs16941239_chr16_86420604_FOXF1_A/T 1468  0,0,0   NA NA <NA> <NA>     <NA>
#>             PL   PS RGQ   SB GT_alleles
#> 1         <NA>   NA  16 <NA>        G/G
#> 2     48,0,498 1344  NA <NA>        C|T
#> 3         <NA>  251  NA <NA>          .
#> 4         <NA>   NA   0 <NA>        C/C
#> 5 32704,3160,0   NA  NA <NA>        C/C
#> 6         <NA>   NA  NA <NA>    AGG/AGG
#> 7         <NA>   NA  NA <NA>          .
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I imagine this isn't an easy task, but if someone has some ideas, or already came across a similar issue... your help would be invaluable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # unnest, pivot_wider

quux %>%
  mutate(across(FORMAT:F1601764_S460_L002, ~ strsplit(., ":"))) %>%
  unnest(c(FORMAT, F1601764_S460_L002)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = setdiff(names(quux), c("FORMAT", "F1601764_S460_L002")), names_from = FORMAT, values_from = F1601764_S460_L002)
# # A tibble: 7 × 17
#   `#CHROM`                               POS ID    REF   ALT   QUAL     FILTER  INFO                                                                                                                                                          GT    AD     DP    GQ    PGT   PID      PL           PS    RGQ  
#   <chr>                                <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>   <chr>                                                                                                                                                         <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>        <chr> <chr>
# 1 rs11218343_chr11_121564878_SORL1_C/T   722 .     AGG   .     29.91    LowQual DP=5;MLEAC=.;MLEAF=.;MQ=26.79                                                                                                                                 0/0   NA     NA    NA    NA    NA       NA           NA    NA   
# 2 rs16941239_chr16_86420604_FOXF1_A/T   1468 .     G     *,GA  .        .       .                                                                                                                                                             ./.   0,0,0  NA    NA    NA    NA       NA           NA    NA   
# 3 rs7384878_chr7_100334426_SPDYE3_C/T   1367 .     C     T     40.64    .       AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=1.29;DP=20;ExcessHet=0.0000;FS=2.963;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=43.87;MQRankSum=-1.058e+00;QD=2.90;ReadPosRankSum=0.697;SOR=1.802 0|1   12,2   14    48    0|1   1344_G_A 48,0,498     1344  NA   
# 4 rs3851179_chr11_86157598_EED_T/C      1000 .     T     C     32690.06 .       AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=1097;ExcessHet=0.0000;FS=0.000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=60.00;QD=31.02;SOR=0.776                                                            1/1   0,1054 1054  99    NA    NA       32704,3160,0 NA    NA   
# 5 rs10868366_chr9_86085145_GOLM1_G/T     246 .     C     .     .        .       .                                                                                                                                                             0/0   0      0     NA    NA    NA       NA           NA    0    
# 6 rs11771145_chr7_143413669_EPHA1_A/G    261 .     T     C     .        .       .                                                                                                                                                             .|.   0,0    NA    NA    0|1   251_T_C  NA           251   NA   
# 7 rs6966331_chr7_37844191_EPDR1_T/C     1384 .     G     .     0.64     LowQual BaseQRankSum=-9.670e-01;DP=3;ExcessHet=0.00;MLEAC=.;MLEAF=.;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.00;ReadPosRankSum=0.967                                                      0/0   NA     3     NA    NA    NA       NA           NA    16
```

---

*Edit*: we don't technically need an unnest/pivot operation here, with larger data they might be a little costly. Try this brute-force that only adds columns:

```r
Map(function(...) as.data.frame(as.list(setNames(...))), strsplit(quux$F1601764_S460_L002, ":"), strsplit(quux$FORMAT, ":")) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  bind_cols(quux, .)
# # A tibble: 7 × 19
#   `#CHROM`                               POS ID    REF   ALT   QUAL     FILTER  INFO                                                FORMAT F1601764_S460_L002 GT    AD    DP    GQ    PGT   PID   PL    PS    RGQ  
#   <chr>                                <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>   <chr>                                               <chr>  <chr>              <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 rs11218343_chr11_121564878_SORL1_C/T   722 .     AGG   .     29.91    LowQual DP=5;MLEAC=.;MLEAF=.;MQ=26.79                       GT     0/0                0/0   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
# 2 rs16941239_chr16_86420604_FOXF1_A/T   1468 .     G     *,GA  .        .       .                                                   GT:AD  ./.:0,0,0          ./.   0,0,0 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
# 3 rs7384878_chr7_100334426_SPDYE3_C/T   1367 .     C     T     40.64    .       AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=1.29;DP=20;ExcessH… GT:AD… 0|1:12,2:14:48:0|… 0|1   12,2  14    48    0|1   1344… 48,0… 1344  NA   
# 4 rs3851179_chr11_86157598_EED_T/C      1000 .     T     C     32690.06 .       AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=1097;ExcessHet=0.0000;FS=0.00… GT:AD… 1/1:0,1054:1054:9… 1/1   0,10… 1054  99    NA    NA    3270… NA    NA   
# 5 rs10868366_chr9_86085145_GOLM1_G/T     246 .     C     .     .        .       .                                                   GT:AD… 0/0:0:0:0          0/0   0     0     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    0    
# 6 rs11771145_chr7_143413669_EPHA1_A/G    261 .     T     C     .        .       .                                                   GT:AD… .|.:0,0:0|1:251_T… .|.   0,0   NA    NA    0|1   251_… NA    251   NA   
# 7 rs6966331_chr7_37844191_EPDR1_T/C     1384 .     G     .     0.64     LowQual BaseQRankSum=-9.670e-01;DP=3;ExcessHet=0.00;MLEAC=… GT:DP… 0/0:3:16           0/0   NA    3     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    16
```

You can look at the value after `bind_rows()` to see *just* the new columns being added.

You suggested in a comment that you always have the same columns, I don't think that necessarily helps us here: we might use regex to find each of `"GT"`, `"DP"`, etc in `FORMAT`, but since we don't have all of them every row, we don't know which position they are in ahead of time, making extraction and pairing with the `F16*` field values a bit onerous. I think using the same `strsplit` approach as the first, but manually creating the columns, is a better plan for larger data.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This worked wonders, and exactly what I wanted to do! Million thanks! You made my day! :) 
I was just wondering... Given that there are only 6 different values on the `FORMAT` field, and I have VCF files with a lot of rows (millions)... do you have any suggestions on how to make the process faster? Again... thank you so much! You are a star!

Comment: I see nine different values in `FORMAT`: they are `c("AD", "DP", "GQ", "GT", "PGT", "PID", "PL", "PS", "RGQ")`. Am I missing something in the count?

Comment: Thank you so much for your additional clarifications! Honestly, I just think you are some sort of a magician! :) I have to confess that I do not know exactly how many different elements exist in the `FORMAT` column. But you are right: programmatically, we will need a strategy that reads one line, evaluates which elements exist on the `FORMAT` column, and match the values on the `F1601764_S460_L002` column, to those.

Comment: Just to give a bit more of context, the VCF file for sample `F1601764_S460_L002`, has a dimension of 205,225 × 10. I actually applied the `unnest` and `Map` solutions to this (and other VCF files). Using the `rbenchmark` package for 5 replicates, the first solution takes 2.034 and the second, 110.131 for the above VCF! Thus, your first suggestion was magic and spot on! Can't thank you enough!